# NO data for the hive table created from avsc schema

Tags: hive, sqoop

I imported data from mysql to hdfs as avroformat. I moved the .avsc file to hdfs and creating hive table by using the .avsc file. Please see the table below:

.AVSC file :  -rw-r--r--   3 jonnavithulasivakrishna hdfs       1041 2017-09-13 00:05 hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna/products.avsc

Table created :

```
hive (siv_sqoop_import)> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Products_1
                       > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
                       > STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
                       > OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
                       > location '/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna/products'
                       > TBLPROPERTIES('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna/products.avsc');
OK
Time taken: 0.155 seconds
hive (siv_sqoop_import)> select * from Products_1 limit 10;
OK
Time taken: 0.294 seconds
```

As you see, it has created with no data.Could you please help me why I'm not getting data in this table.

Comment: Share your sqoop command , also try adding defaultFS "hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/" to location also.

Comment: Please find the sqoop command below :

Comment: did you tried "hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna/products" as location

Comment: Yes ,I tried "hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna‌​/products" as well.Still it is showing no data.

Comment: whats the output of hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna‌​‌​/products
and
hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna‌​‌​/products/*

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sqoop command below :

sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://nn01.itvserity.com:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba -P \
--table products \
--as-avrodatafile \
--num-mappers 6 \
--target-dir "/user/jonnavithulasivakrishna/products" \